# SharePoint Online Linked Data Source Error

Tags: sharepoint-online

Using SharePoint Designer on SharePoint Online I am trying to link lists together with Linked Data Source to create a View.  I get "Data Source file cannot be saved".

I am a site collection owner and Site owner.

I have ensured that the name, description and Keywords are completed, but connot get this to work.

Any help will be appreciated

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Go through with this [Link](http://ignatiuz.com/blog/how-to-link-two-lists-and-create-a-combined-view-in-sharepoint-2013/). You can link two SharePoint lists and create a combined view using SharePoint Designer `Data Sources`.